# How to add onto a class after its definition?

Tags: javascript, class, project, inner-classes

I have a big class, called game, and it has many nested classes and functions.

```js
class Game {
  constructor(opts) {

    this.Thing = class {
      constructor() {
        //do stuff
      }
      //a ton of functions
    }
    //a ton of functions

  }
}
```

I would like a way to organize it and make it easier to develop.

I was thinking of splitting the class up into multiple files, but I don't know how that would work.

**Is there any way for me split this class up into multiple files? If not how else can I organize it, is there a better way?**

Answer (score 1):

One way to make this less verbose is to define some (or all) of the functions within other files. Just make sure you use the `function` keyword instead of an arrow function so that when you reference `this`, you're referencing the class it eventually gets put into. For instance, you can do something like this in one file:

```js
export function method() {}
```

and then include it like this in your main file:

```js
import { method } from './method';

class BigClass {
  constructor() {}

  method = method
}
```

Any reference to `this` within the method will refer to the instance it's called on.

As for nested classes, you should just be able to export the class from another file like so:

```js
export class OtherClass {
   constructor() {}
}
```

```js
import { OtherClass } from './otherclass'

class BigClass {
  constructor() {}

  OtherClass = OtherClass;
}
```

Comment: I got `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. import call expects exactly one argument.`

Comment: I set type = module, but now I get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Game`

Comment: I think I'd have to see your code to know what the `SyntaxError` is about. Same for the `ReferenceError`, but where are you trying to call `Game` that it's giving you a reference error?

Comment: In the file I use to test the library. The Syntax error was from this line of code `import { Camera } from 'camera.js'`
@Connor Mooneyhan

Comment: If I can get this working, I will mark your answer as correct

Comment: @Hg0428 I don't know your file structure but a couple options for why that's happening would be that a) you haven't specified the file path accurately. Just "camera.js" would refer to the root of the application, so if that's not your intention, check that. b) it could be that you're not working within a "module." Check the MDN docs for "import" if you think this might be the case. Sorry, I couldn't share the link for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I found a solution that works better for me and gives me more options.

Comment: @Hg0428 excellent, I'm glad! Post it as an answer here if you can; I'd like to see it!

Comment: I would, but my solution won't help anyone else all that much.
I wrote a program to read through my files and find the special command `!!place {filename} here` and replace it with the contents of that file, then to go through and fix the indentations.